# Custom Post Type Archive Page: Set Posts Per Page, Paginate

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives, loop

I have a custom post type called `video`. Would like to paginate its archive page, showing **only 3 posts** on each page.

There is also a custom loop on the archive page that outputs **all** the video posts (for a thumbnail gallery).

This is the `archive-video.php`:

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    MAIN LOOP...
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php next_posts_link(); previous_posts_link(); >

<?php $custom_loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
<?php while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); ?>
    CUSTOM LOOP...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I've tried to set the `posts_per_page` to 3 using `pre_get_posts` [(code here)](http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/05/16/wordpress-posts-per-page-per-custom-post-type/). The pagination would work perfectly, but the custom loop now outputs only 3 posts and not all the posts!

Anyone with a hard-coded/non-plugin solution? Have been googling to no avail... Any advice/help would be most appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

The code in the link you posted will (using `pre_get_posts`) will always change the number of posts_per_page to 3 if you are querying posts from that type. So a better solution would be to not use that code and simply above you code, before :

`<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

add:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif ( get_query_var('page') )
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
else
    $paged = 1;
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'paged' => $paged ));
```

and this will only effect that query and not all queries of that post type.

Update:

the structure of your code should look like this:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif ( get_query_var('page') )
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
else
    $paged = 1;
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'paged' => $paged ));
while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    //MAIN LOOP...
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); 

next_posts_link(); previous_posts_link(); 

$custom_loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post();
    //CUSTOM LOOP...
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Noted on your point about the `pre_get_posts`. Tried your code but the pagination links aren't showing up!

Comment: @qwer0o are you getting 3 per page with the full  list? what is the code you are using? I added the structure to the  answer

Comment: Yes I was using the code you'd just added. I'm getting 3 posts output by the MAIN LOOP, and all the posts for the CUSTOM LOOP, but no pagination links.

Comment: I have 7 'video' posts, but the posts per page set in my Reading Settings is 20. Oddly, changing it to 6 or under in the Reading Settings and the pagination appears. Wordpress bug? (In any case, this definitely isn't a proper solution...)

Comment: i had the same issue a while back, you may want to read this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/custom-post-type-archive-404s-with-paginate-links especialy my bit at the end

Comment: try passing max_num_pages to the function:
`next_posts_link('Older Entries »', $max_num_pages);`

Comment: Do you mean to replace `next_posts_link();` with `next_posts_link('Older Entries »', $max_num_pages);`? Still not working, unfortunately. (BTW `var_dump($max_num_pages)` gives NULL.)

Comment: @Bainternet @Martin So, using the code provided in Bainternet's answer, I found that WP is still paging out the archive page based on the value set in the Settings! What I mean is: with 7 'video' posts, setting to **1 post per page** in the Reading Settings results in the archive becoming 7 pages -- first two pages have 3 posts each, third page has 1 post, while on the last four pages the pagination links are there but there are no posts!

Comment: This is affecting term archive result for the specific custom post type. That should be factored into the query too.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `pre_get_posts` hook in your case and I would filter the main query. Add the following code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'video' ) && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );
  }
} );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try `'paged' => $paged,` after `new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'video',` and change `'posts_per_page' => '-1'` to `'posts_per_page' => '3'`